# Not able to connect a Docker container to MongoDB Atlas using uri connection string

Tags: docker, mongodb-atlas

I have a Linux VM in which Docker v18.0.0ce is installed.

I have a tomcat container in Docker with my java application installed on it. But when i try to use the connection string from the MongoDb Atlas in my database configuration file, its not even connecting to the MongoDb Atlas.

```
mongodb://database:password@cluster0-shard-00-00-ddxdd.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-ddxdd.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-ddxdd.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin
```

The above is the connection string, I've replaced the `<PASSWORD>` with my password and `test` with `admin` for database name.

Comment: 1) What's the error/message/exception ? 2) What's your Java code snippet to connect ? 3) Which MongoDB Java driver version are you using ?

Comment: data:
        mongodb:
            uri: mongodb://database:password@cluster0-shard-00-00-ddxdd.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-ddxdd.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-ddxdd.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin


Mongodb v3.4

There is no error message on tomcat logs, just a 404 not found on local host logs.